# How can I determine the Q value of a tuned square loop?

Tags: antenna

How can I determine the formula for Q value of a tuned square loop?  How do I find the Q value practically?

Comment: Try this https://coil32.net/download-coil64-for-windows.html and this https://www.translatorscafe.com/unit-converter/fr-FR/calculator/planar-coil-inductance/

Comment: Can you please provide an example to make it more clear and easier to answer.

Comment: "RF Microelectronics", Balanis, chapter 7.

Comment: What are the specs of your "coil"? At what frequencies?